# Split string on semicolons immediately followed by 7 digital characters

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
2234323,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;4534453,23,23,44,433;
3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
7545455,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
```

As you see, there are semicolons between values. I want to split this string based on 'only semicolons before 7 digits values' so I should have this:

```
>2234323,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
>4534453,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;
>7545455,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
```

the only thing that I can think of is `explode(';',$string)` but this returns this:

```
>2234323,23,23,44,433;
>3,23,44,433;
>23,23,44,433;
>23,23,44,433
>4534453,23,23,44,433;
>3,23,44,433;
>23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;
>7545455,23,23,44,433;
>3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;
>23,23,44,433
```

Is there any fast method to split string with this format based on the ";" before 7 digits values?

Comment: use regular expresion to match semicolon (;) and comma (,).
`array preg_split ( string $pattern , string $subject [, int $limit = -1 [, int $flags = 0 ]] )` use preg_split().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` for that:

```
$s = '2234323,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;4534453,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;7545455,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433';
var_dump(preg_split('/(;\d{7},)/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

Your output will be

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(58) "2234323,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433"
  [1] =>
  string(9) ";4534453,"
  [2] =>
  string(50) "23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433"
  [3] =>
  string(9) ";7545455,"
  [4] =>
  string(50) "23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433"
}
```

I think that the next thing (combine the 1st and 2nd and then 3rd and 4th elements) is not a big deal :)

Let me know if you still here problems here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a find and replace on numbers that are seven digits long, to insert a token that you can use to split. The output may need a little extra filtering to get to your desired format.

```
<?php
$in =<<<IN
2234323,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;4534453,23,23,44,433;
3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
7545455,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
IN;

$out = preg_replace('/([0-9]{7})/', "@$1", $in);
$out = explode('@', $out);
$out = array_filter($out);

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => '2234323,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;',
  2 => '4534453,23,23,44,433;
3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
',
  3 => '7545455,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input structure seems a little unstable, but once it is stabilized, just use `preg_split()` to match (and consume) semicolons that are immediately followed by exactly 7 digits.  `\b` is a word boundary to ensure that their is no 8th digit.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JRUie))

```
$string = <<<STR
2234323,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;4534453,23,23,44,433;
3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
7545455,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433
STR;

$string = preg_replace('/;?\R/', ';', $string);  // I don't know if this is actually necessary for your real project

var_export(
    preg_split('/;(?=\d{7}\b)/', $string)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '2234323,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433',
  1 => '4534453,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433',
  2 => '7545455,23,23,44,433;3,23,44,433;23,23,44,433;23,23,44,433',
)
```